# Windows kernel mode driver developing

Tags: driver, windows-kernel, windows-driver

I'm a C++ and C# developer,but rookie in windows driver developing.I encounter a problem and get confused.my question is how to develop driver without vs2019? In another word how are kernel mode drivers were developed before driver developing capability was added to visual studio? Unfortunately despite of looking a lot for developing driver without vs,I'm not so successful about finding an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Install WDK 7600
It's an old version of WDK that came out as standardone without a visual studio.

The help is very good, so it is said that it is good to use this help without searching on MSDN.